# Twice order in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I need order collection twice.
I do it so

```
query = query
            .OrderBy(p => p.Status == 2)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Status == 3)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Status == 1)
```

and I need order each group by adding date.
It possible?

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you want. What do you mean with *order each group by adding date*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set conditions in a OrderBy and you need only one order by on p.Status, then you can add a second order level using the date property/field of your class.

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.Status)
             .ThenBy(p => p.SomeDate)
```

However, after your edit, it is clear that this solution is not enough.
Now you need to force a custom sort order like the one below.

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => (p.Status == 1 ? 3 
                                          : (p.Status == 2 ? 1 
                                                           : 2)))
             .ThenBy(p => p.SomeDate)
```

Of course this is possible only if you have a limited set of values for the Status property. Otherwise you need a more complex solution that requires that your entity implements the [IComparer interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) in such a way that [OrderBy can use it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Of course you need to write yourself the code that tracks all the possible values of Status and its relative sort order.
All in all, perhaps it is more simple (if feasible) to add another property to your entity that express the sort order required